# Vxworks shell grep functionality

Tags: vxworks

Is there any function in VxWorks shell that can be used like grep in
unix, To filter the output of commands like

> i | grep "myTask" , so
>   that I get only those lines for "myTask"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to `grep` output from the `i` command, you could use a more specific function to get the id of the desired task.

```
TaskNameToId("myTask")
```

Then you could pass that id into taskShow:

```
NAME

    taskShow( ) - display task information from TCBs

SYNOPSIS

    STATUS taskShow
        (
        int tid,                  /* task ID */
        int level                 /* 0 = summary, 1 = details, 2 = all tasks */
        )
```